# what happens when we call a class?

Tags: python, object

From python in a nutshell,

> Where C is a class, the statement `x=C(23)` is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> x = C.__new__(C, 23) 
> if isinstance(x, C): type(x).__init__(x, 23)
> ```

From my understanding `object.__new__` creates a new, uninitialized instance of the class it receives as its first argument.

Why is there need to be a check with the `isinstance()`. Isn't it obvious that `__new__` will return a object of type `C`.

If it is what happens if this test fails?

Since `classes` are `callables`, is the call to `__new__` is done in the class's `__call()__` method

Am I missing something here, please clarify this to me

Comment: Nothing happens if that test fails, you just don't call `__init__`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

Comment: If you override `__new__`, it can return anything you like.

Comment: @jonrsharpe then the constructed object isn't initialised?

Comment: @CongestedSerpent - If a `__new__` implementation returns a different class, then that implementation is responsible for handing init. See `pathlib.py` for example. Such a class can be challenging to inherit from.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you for the reference. I will study it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't it obvious that `__new__` will return a object of type C.

Not at all. The following is valid:

```
>>> class C:
...   def __new__(cls):
...     return "not a C"
...   def __init__(self):
...     print("Never called")
...
>>> C()
'not a C'
```

When you override `__new__`, you will *probably* return an instance of `cls`, but you aren't *required* to. This is useful for defining factory classes, which don't create instances of themselves but rather instances of other classes.

Note that you quote is not quite accurate. `x = C(32)` is equivalent, at the first step, to `x = type.__call__(C, 32)`. It is `type.__call__` that calls `C.__new__`, then decides whether to invoke the return value's `__init__` method.

You can think of `type.__call__` as being defined something like

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return obj
```

Applying this to `C`, we see that `obj` is set to the `str` value `'not a C'`, not an instance of `C`, so that `'not a C'.__init__` is not called before returning the string.

Comment: This solved the most of my problems. Can you specify the role of `__call__ ()` this situation

Comment: Thank you very much this is an explaining answer.

Comment: Just did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

[isinstance(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) is used to check if a is instance of b. Not sure why you checking it after creation. Magical methods can be redefined. Although in normal cases isinstance() is needed to check dynamic data.

Comment: OP is just demonstrating what python does in the case a different object type is returned from `__new__`.